# how to related two fields whose they are not principal keys?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have 3 tables:

```
class users
    columns={
          name=fields.char(....
          sucursal_user:fields.many2one('sucursales',...}
users()

class sucursales
    columns={
          name=fields.char(....
          }
sucursales()

class orders
    columns={
          name=fields.char(....
          sucursal_order:fields.many2one('sucursales',...}
orders()
```

How I can list if I log into the system and I am form 'italy's sucursal I want to list all the orders from Italy

So I need to list users and orders tables where `sucursal_user` and `sucursal_order` are equals.

I made a query and works but I don't know how to do it in openerp.

```
select * from res_users, ordenes_orden
where sucursal_u = sucursal
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the users and orders related for a particular sucursales record, you can create a one2many field such that those values are shown to you.

```
class sucursales
    columns = {
       'user_ids': fields.one2many('res.users', 'sucursal_user', string="Related users"),
       'order_ids': fields.one2many('sale.order', 'sucursal_order', string='Related Orders'),
    }
```

Comment: domain="[('user_ids[uid].sucursal_u','=','orden_ids.sucursal')]" and how i can do the domain filter i want all orders from current(logged) user's sucursal

Comment: try this domain = **"[('sucursal_order','=',user.sucursal_user.id)]"** 

we are going to use the sucursal_user value available at user to filter the sale orders

Comment: it showed me in the tree view (41 records) and its ok but doesn't show me the 41 records i need to display in the tree view the 41 records,

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand your previous comment

Comment: I assume that some of your sales order are in quotation and confirmed states.  If they have different states, obviously all 41 records will not be shown at Quotation or Sales order menu.

Comment: i have sucursal that means other strores in other cities if the user is from one that call "italy" i need all orders on ly from italy, i counted on the screen how many were them and they are 41, so in the view tree appears the user and in parentesis (41 records) and its ok but i want the 41 records in a tree view jejeje my brain hurts i had tried a lot of things